# alertdialog positive/negative buttons are not matching parent in fullscreen dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

In OnCreateDialog in my dialogfragment class i am doing this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_spending_fragment_layout,null);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                });
        builder.setView(v);
        return builder.create();
```

In OnStart in the dialogfragment class i am making the dialogfragment fullscreen

```
Dialog d = getDialog();
        if (d!=null){
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
```

I want the postive button (Fire) in the alertdialog to show in bottom.

Emulator preview:

[image]

The layout i am inflating has width and height set to match parent.

I have added an empty view in my inflated layout (R.layout.new_spending_fragment_layout) and set its params to match parent in xml which is fixing the problem but i think is a temporary answer.

I also want to remove padding (or gaps) from all sides.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, [Dialog with fullscreen screenshot](http://prntscr.com/dd5seq)

1 - Create dialog

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar); // Replace this line
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.show();
```

2 - dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Hello this is demo textview"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Fire"
            android:background="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't add child views in a View. So I changed your view to linearlayout but its not working for it (or any viewgroup i guess). Try to add any textview or button as child in your view.

Comment: Well I think you have to create dialog with custom view, I've modified code, have a look and let me know for another queries

Comment: Okay, its working with dialog. I also want to remove padding on sides. Thanks

Comment: I wanted it to work with alertdialog. I am using dialog now but i don't know how to remove padding on all sides. I want the dialog to fill entire screen.

Comment: Did you see screenshot that I've attached above ??? Dialog is covering the whole screen

Comment: yes, it is also working for me. But there is small padding/gap from  edges of screen.

Comment: Please check my modified answer...and have a look at screenshot